# Ajax работает локально, но не работает на удаленном сервере

Tags: ajax

```
 $("#order").submit(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault(); 
              alert("stop"); 
              $.ajax({
                  type: "post",
                  url: "post.php",
                  data: $(this).serialize(),
                  success: function(result){console.log(result)},
                  error: function(err){console.log(err);}
              })
```

Тысячу раз перепроверял, ошибок в консоли нет, все чисто. На локальной машине все работает, на удаленном сервере - нет. Тысячу раз перепроверил.Там, где выставлен alert - последняя точка, где он срабатывает.

Comment: То есть не выполняется ни `success`, ни `error`, и в консоли никаких ошибок?

Comment: Ну так подебажь, посмотри, какой запрос посылается и что возвращает сервер.

Comment: нет, не выполняется ни черта - и в консоли все чисто. http://form.transkribator.ru

Comment: Как же не выполняется? Пачками запросы шлются... У вас сервер что-то помирает...

Comment: Похоже потому и помирает, что каждый N-й клик отправляет N запросов

Comment: Состояние `penging` у запросов, сервер игнорит

Answer (score 0):

У вас по клику на кнопку добавляется обработчик события отправки формы.
Так как кнопка submit, она же отправляет форму.

В итоге, каждый следующий клик инициирует +N ajax запросов. Сервер не отвечает. Таймаут на сервере слишком большой, порядка 14 минут.

Почините скрипт, перезагрузите сервер(http-сервер, не reboot)

Для починки выберите один из двух вариантов:

- Исключите btn.click с кнопки, сразу form.submit(...)
- Исключите form.submit, всё обрабатывайте в btn.click, type кнопки смените на button

---

**Ещё раз.**

`$(form).submit` - это не "всё хорошо, отправляем форму", а "когда форма будет отправлена - выполни эту функцию".
Проще говоря, обработчик события `submit` формы.

Comment: поменял тип кнопки - не работает

Comment: Ну так этого недостаточно, читайте внимательнее

Comment: Вот это: `$("#order").submit(function(e) {` надо удалить. Вызов `$.ajax` перенесите в обработчик клика по кнопке.

Comment: там же условие стоит: при клике на кнопку если имеется определенный класс - выполняем действия  - иначе: сабмит формы с id="order"

Comment: никакого сабмита.... $ajax() - твой сабмит

Comment: Прочитайте секцию **Ещё раз** ответа

Comment: наверное, я просто туплю, как веник. На локальной работает - на удаленном нет